# C# WPF стиль с тоггл кнопкой и картинкой

Tags: c#, wpf

День добрый.

Имеется в наличии следующий стиль:

```
<Style x:Key="Style_MainButtons" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="110" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="110" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Text" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Image x:Name="Image" Grid.Row="1" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                              
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Так как кнопок несколько и каждая имеет свой текст и картинку, то хотелось бы присваивать содержание текста и адрес картинки в следующем коде:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnHorizontal" 
              Style="{StaticResource Style_MainButtons}"
              Grid.Column="0" 
              Grid.Row="1" 
              Checked ="SetVersion" 
              Unchecked ="SetVersion" 
              IsChecked="True" >
</ToggleButton>
```

Как сие можно исполнить?

Comment: Ну так положите пару attached property, делов-то. Для текста можно вообще использовать `Content`.

Comment: @VladD , а можно поподробнее? Так как ковыряние в интернете «attached property» ничего подходящего не дало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего, наверное, так.

Для начала, добавьте к `ToggleButton` attached property, из которого вы будете читать картинку. (Это проще всего сделать, используя сниппет `propa`.)

```
public static class ToggleButtonExtensions
{
    public static ImageSource GetImageSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(ImageSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetImageSource(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ToggleButtonExtensions),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Теперь модифицируем шаблон, чтобы он читал текст из `Content`, а источник для картинки из добавленного attached property. (Обратите внимание на синтаксис с круглыми скобками.)

```
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Text" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            <Image x:Name="Image" Grid.Row="1"
                   Source="{Binding (local:ToggleButtonExtensions.ImageSource),
                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
```

И пользуемся:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnHorizontal" 
      Style="{StaticResource Style_MainButtons}"
      IsChecked="True"
      local:ToggleButtonExtensions.ImageSource="logo4w.png">
    Всем привет, я Пикачу!
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Странно, что подобные вещи не реализованы в языке по умолчанию.

Comment: @Arik: Пожалуйста! // С языком проблема в том, что WPF как библиотека находится вне языка, так что приходится выкручиваться.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял то вам надо просто в стили binding-и добавить

```
<Style x:Key="Style_MainButtons" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="110" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="110" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Grid.Row="1" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

И соответственно во ViewModel иметь свойства Text и Image.

Если стиль используется как шаблон для панели инструментов, изменяя только image и text, то надо использовать TemplateBinding:

```
Content="{TemplateBinding SomeProperty}"
```

, где SomeProperty — свойство-источник для подстановки в template.

Comment: <TextBlock Content="{Binding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" /> 
выбрасывает ошибочку: «The property 'Content' was not found in type 'TextBlock'»

Comment: Да, конечно же там Text